# How to detect elements with shadow dom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

I'm trying to detect if an extension is installed by checking if it adds a specific div inside the body.

When the extension is installed it adds the following div in the end of the body:

```
<div>
  #shadow-root (closed)
    <div id="extension_name">
      <!--div content here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to detect this element with a simple document query like:

`document.body.queryselector(':shadow-root #extension-name')`

If not, any suggestion about an efficient way to check if this element exists?

Comment: If the extension created the element in its content script (i.e. not in [page context](/a/9517879)) then there's no way for the page to peek into a closed shadow root. In case of page context, it depends on timing: if the extension doesn't safe-guard itself against spoofing then you can hook Element.prototype.attachShadow.

Comment: If you attach a shadow root to a custom element with mode: closed set, you won't be able to access the shadow DOM from the outside [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM#basic_usage)

Answer (score 1):

So looks like it's impossible to get the information when the shadow dom is closed. So I had to find alternative ways to detect the extension.

When it's open we can query using:

```
const isInstalled = Array.from(window.document.body.children).reverse().find(
  (item) => item.localName === 'div' && item.shadowRoot !== null && item.shadowRoot.querySelector('#extension_name')
) !== undefined;
```

Ps: Most of the extensions append the div on the end of the body. So `reverse` is intended to optimize the query.

Thanks @wOxxOm and @Louys Patrice Bessette for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

- doesn't detect when there are multiple/nested shadowRoots
- doesn't detect when *any* of those is a `closed` shadowRoot

**instead**

- Make you component listen at `document` level for a  `extension_name` Event
- Let your testcode dispatch a `extension_name` Event

You can even pass a function in `event.detail` and let your extension execute it